# Vue computed property: helper function returns undefined despite being defined

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a computed property `diameter()` to return either:
- a random number (`randomise: true`)
- a number returned from an object within an array (`randomise: false`).

I do have a working implementation (see bottom of post) but would like to know why the cleaner implementation doesn't work. With `randomise: false`, `diameter()` returns `undefined`. Why?

```
vars [
  {varName: diameter, varValue: 25.8},
  {varName: quantity, varValue: 68}
]
```

```
computed: {
  diameter() {
    if (randomise) {
      return math.randomInt(100, 1000) //no problems
    } else {
      console.log(this.populateValue('diameter')) //undefined
      return this.populateValue('diameter')
    }
  }
}
```

```
methods: {
    populateValue(variableName) {
      this.vars.forEach(element => {
        if (element.varName === variableName) {
          console.log(element.varValue) //25.8
          return element.varValue
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

The following implementation works but why do I have to create an arbitrary property to do so?

```
diameter() {
  if (!this.vars || !this.passVars) {
    return math.randomInt(100, 1000) / (10 ** math.randomInt(0, 3))
  } else {
    this.populateValue('diameter')
    return this.blah
  }
}
```

```
populateValue(variableName) {
  this.vars.forEach(element => {
    if (element.varName === variableName) {
      this.blah = element.varValue
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: As skirtle mentioned, you are returning from forEach, and then returning nothing for the method. There are some ways to fix this, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/xeh1g3zy/1/ where you assign a local variable and return that. Sadly there is no way to grab the value returned by forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `return element.varValue` is returning from the `forEach`, not `populateValue`.

There are various ways to write this. e.g.

```js
for (const element of this.vars) {
  if (element.varName === variableName) {
    return element.varValue
  }  
}
```

By using a `for`/`of` loop there is no inner function so the `return` returns from the function you're expecting.

Alternatives include:

```js
let value = null

this.vars.forEach(element =>
  if (element.varName === variableName) {
    value = element.varValue
  }  
})

return value
```

or:

```js
const match = this.vars.find(element =>
  return element.varName === variableName
})

if (match) {
  return match.varValue
}
```